# how to use the random image command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a random picture selection using my computer files instead of internet ones.

Here is my beta code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('L!pat')) {
        let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to pat them!!');
        // message goes below!
        message.channel.send(`${targetMember.user}, You just got a pat!"`); 
        message.channel.send({files:["./pats/pat.gif"]})
        ranfile = Math.floor(Math.random() * file.length);
        message.channel.sendFile(ranfile);
        //let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        //embed.setImage(`https://toxicmuffin.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/tumblr_mkzqyghtsm1r0rp7xo1_400.gif`)
        message.channel.send;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a folder with all your pictures, and name them with numbers increasing, so e.g.
   1.png, 2.png, 3.png. Make sure every photo has the same format (png)
2. Random Number generator:
3. Code:

```
const num = (Math.floor(Math.random()*<how many pictures you have>)+1).toString();
message.channel.send({files: [`./paths/${num}.png`]});
```

Make sure your directory is right, I am also not sure about how to send a photo, but the directory part should work for sure.